# Callbacks with ctypes (How to call a python function from C)

Tags: python, ctypes

Is it possible to call a Python function from a C `dll` function?

We consider this C function:

```
 void foo( void (*functionPtr)(int,int) , int a, int b);
```

On Python, I would like to call `foo` and set the callback to a Python function:

```
def callback(a, b):
    print("foo has finished its job (%d, %d)" % (a.value,b.value))

dll.foo( callback, c_int(a), c_int(b) )
```

Unfortunately, the `ctypes` documentation is pretty light on this topic and the above code does not work.

Comment: Ctypes callback documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#callback-functions

Comment: The tutorial is often the de facto reference for ctypes, unfortunately. Mark gave you the tutorial link, but surely it's documented enough in the [reference section 2.4](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#function-prototypes) to get beyond what you tried: "Function prototypes created by these factory functions can be instantiated in different ways, depending on the type and number of the parameters in the call ... prototype(callable), Create a C callable function (a callback function) from a Python callable".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
import ctypes as c

@c.CFUNCTYPE(None, c.c_int, c.c_int)
def callback(a, b):
    print("foo has finished its job (%d, %d)" % (a.value, b.value))

dll.foo(callback, a, b) # assuming a,b are ints
```

If you need `stdcall` calling conventions, [use `WINFUNCTYPE` instead](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE).

Note: if `foo` may store the callback to be called at a later time then make sure that Python callback is alive (it is enough if it is defined at the global level using the decorator as shown in the example -- modules are essentially immortal in Python unless you try to remove them explicitly).

Comment: Good use of decorator there

Answer (score 4):

Use `CFUNCTYPE` to create a callback type:

```
c_callback = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_int, c_int)(callback)
dll.foo(c_callback, a, b)
```

Comment: OP was being explicit, so I was too.