# C# callbacks with return values in Python

Tags: python, c#, interop, ctypes

I am trying to call the following function in a DLL, which (to my limited understanding), takes a callback as a parameter.

C# definitions:

```
//Error handler
public delegate int FPtrErrorHandler(int ErrorType, int MessageType, int WhomToInform, String ErrorMessage);

//Desired function to call
[ DllImport ( Globals.LibDLLPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl ) ]
public static extern int OpenLib(String TempDirectory, Bool IfCleanTempDir, FPtrErrorHandler ErrorHandler);
```

Per [this SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484591/callbacks-with-ctypes-how-to-call-a-python-function-from-c), I created the Python code below:

```
import ctypes as c
from ctypes import *

@c.WINFUNCTYPE(c.c_int, c.c_int, c.c_int, c.c_int, c.c_char_p)
def FPtrErrorHandler(ErrorIdentifier, ErrorMessageType, WhomToInform, ErrorMessage):
    print(f'Error ID={ErrorIdentifier}, Type={ErrorMessageType}, WhomToInform={WhomToInform}, msg={ErrorMessage}')
    return 0

lib = windll.LoadLibrary('path_to_dll')

_OpenLib = lib[163]
_OpenLib.restype = c_int
_OpenLib.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_bool, c_void_p]
def OpenLib(TempDirectory,IfCleanTempDir):
    cb1 = FPtrErrorHandler
    return _OpenLib(TempDirectory, IfCleanTempDir, cb1)

n = OpenLib(r:'c:\temp',c_bool(True))
```

Unfortunately, I get the dreaded message

`ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type`

Thanks in advance for helping me with this.  I'm really happy to learn ctypes and how to use Python to interact with the amazing DLLs that are out there.

Comment: I'm not sure how python interacts with foreign code, but the c# `FPtrErrorHandler` has defined 4 parameters. But your python `FPtrErrorHandler` has only 3 parameter. Isn't that wrong?

Comment: Also it seems like the first argument `c.c_char_p` of `c.WINFUNCTYPE` needs to be the return type. But the c# method return `int` and therfore should be `c.c_int`, right?

Comment: Good questions -- I must say I'm not clear on this myself.  I'm assuming that the ErrorMessage in ```FPtrErrorHandler``` is an output parameter, hence the ```c.c_char_p``` as the first argument to ```c.WINFUNCTYPE```.  However, I'm open to suggestions regarding what to change.

Comment: `ErrorMessage` is defintly not an outpur parameter, if it would be it would be annoted with the `out` keyword. The sigature shows that the return type is an `int`.

Comment: @Ackdari, Based on your feedback, I changed the code as currently shown.  However, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Maybe the problem comes from `c_void_p` of the `argstypes`

Comment: Yes, very well could be.  However, I don't know what to put there.  For example, I tried ```POINTER(c_void_p)``` and ```_NOpenNestLib(TempDirectory,IfCleanTempDir,pointer(cb1))``` but the error remains.  I wish I knew how to properly handle the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

OMG, I think this might be an easy one.

If I change the call to the function from

```
n = OpenLib(r:'c:\temp',c_bool(True))
```

to

```
n = OpenLib(rb:'c:\temp',c_bool(True))
```

it seems to be working.  I just added the `b` modifier in the string prefix.